# Which texts have you read?

Tags: discussion, community

I asked a couple of questions on Nyaya and Vaisheshika. I did not receive any answers, I presume because no one on here has read those texts yet. Hence, I ask this question, as I believe it will give everyone an idea on what questions are more likely to be answered and what questions to ask.

Comment: nice perspective of maintaining quality on this site :)

Comment: what questions to ask.-- I am afraid that won't be the case. No user will check this post and the 5 answers before asking their questions. They will ask whatever questions they are being bothered with.

Answer (score 18):

Note: I don't generally read Hindu scriptures and works linearly from beginning to end. So here is a list of some of the texts I've read in English, in whole or in part:

Samhitas of the Vedas:

- Rig Veda Samhita
- Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda
- Vajasaneyi Samhita of the Yajur Veda
- Sama Veda Samhita
- Atharvana Veda Samhita

Brahmanas of the Vedas:

- Aitareya Brahmana of the Rig Veda
- Kaushitaki Brahmana of the Rig Veda
- Taittiriya Brahmana of the Yajur Veda
- Shatapatha Brahmana of the Yajur Veda
- Jaiminiya Brahmana of the Sama Veda
- Panchavimsha Brahmana of the Sama Veda

Aranyakas of the Vedas:

- Shankhayana Aranyaka of the Rig Veda
- Aitareya Aranyaka of the Rig Veda
- Taittiriya Aranyaka of the Yajur Veda
- Brihad Aranyaka of the Yajur Veda
- Jaiminiya Upanishad Brahmana of the Sama Veda

Upanishads of the Vedas:

- Isha
- Kena
- Katha
- Mandukya
- Kaushitaki
- Kali Santarana
- Prashna
- Mundaka
- Aitareya
- Taittiriya
- Brihadaranyaka
- Chandogya
- Shvetashvarara
- Mahanarayana
- Narasimha Tapani
- Brahma
- Dattatreya
- Ganapati Atharvashirsha
- Narayana
- Mudgala
- Jabala
- Brihadjabala
- Mandala Brahmana
- Varaha
- Maitrayaniya
- Muktika
- Atharvashira
- Dakahinamurthi

Agamas:

- Lakshmi Tantra
- Parama Samhita
- Brahma Samhita
- Brihadbrahma Samhita
- Narada Pancharatra
- Raurava Agama
- Kirana Agama
- Nishvasatattva Samhita
- Yogini Hridaya
- Vijnana Bhairava Tantra
- Manthana Bhairava Tantra
- Todala Tantra
- Paratrimshika
- Paushkara Tantra
- Mahanirvana Tantra

Itihasas:

- Valmiki Ramayana
- Vyasa's Mahabharata

Puranas:

- 18 Mahapuranas
- Devi Bhagavatam
- Vishnudharmottara Pursna
- Kalki Purana

Darshana Sutras:

- Jaimini's Purva Mimamsa Sutras
- Vyasa's Brahma Sutras
- Kapila's Samkhya Sutras
- Patanjali's Yoga Sutras
- Gautama's Nyaya Sutras
- Kanada's Vaisheshika Sutras
- Vasugupta's Shiva Sutras
- Lakulisha's Pashupata Sutras

Shrauta Sutras:

- Manava Shrauta Sutras
- Vaikhanasa Shrauta Sutras
- Shankhayana Shrauta Sutras
- Baudhayana Shrauta Sutras
- Katyayana Shrauta Sutras

Grihya Sutras:

- Shankhayana Grihya Sutras
- Ashvalayana Grihya Sutras
- Paraskara Grihya Sutras
- Khadira Grihya Sutras
- Gobhila Grihya Sutras
- Hiranyakeshi Grihya Sutras
- Apastamba Grihya Sutras
- Vaikhanasa Grihya Sutras

Dharma Shastras:

- Manu Smriti
- Parashara Smriti
- Yagnavalkya Smriti
- Vishnu Smriti
- Apastamba Dharama Sutras
- Gautama Dharma Sutras
- Vasishta Dharma Sutras
- Baudhayana Dharma Sutras
- Vaikhanasa Dharma Sutras

Bhakti Sutras:

- Narada Bhakti Sutras
- Shandilya Bhakti Sutras

Commentaries on the Brahma Sutras:

- Adi Shankaracharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya
- Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya
- Madhvacharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya
- Baladeva Vidyabhushana's Govinda Bhashya
- Nimbarkacharya's Vedanta Parijata Saurabha
- Srikantha Shivacharya's Srikantha Bhashya

Commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita:

- Adi Shankaracharya
- Ramanujacharya
- Madhvacharya
- Srila Bhaktivedanta Prabhupada
- Abhinavagupta
- Keshava Kashmiri
- Sridhara Swami
- Jnaneshwar

Commentaries on the Upanishads:

- Adi Shankaracharya
- Ranga Ramanuja
- Madhvacharya
- Vedanta Desikan
- Srila Bhaktivedanta Prabhupada

Sri Vaishnava philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Nathamuni's Naalayira Divya Prabandham
- Yamunacharya's Agama Pramanya
- Yamunacharya's Gitartha Sangraha
- Yamunacharya's Chatussloki
- Yamunacharya's Atma Siddhi
- Yamunacharya's Ishwara Siddhi
- Yamunacharya's Samvit Siddhi
- Ramanujacharya's Vedanta Sara
- Ramanujacharya's Vedanta Dipa
- Ramanujacharya's Vedartha Sangraha
- The Thirukollur Penpillai Rahasyam
- Vangipuram Nambi's Virodhi Pariharam
- Parashara Bhattar's Bhagavad Guna Darpana
- Nadadur Ammal’s Prapanna Parijata
- Sudarshana Suri’s commentary on the Sharanagati Gadyam
- Pillai Lokacharya's Tattva Traya
- Pillai Lokacharya's Sri Vachana Bhushanam
- Pillai Lokacharya's Artha Panchaka
- Pillai Lokacharya's Mumukshupadi
- Pillai Lokacharya's Prapanna Paritrana
- Azhagiya Manavala Perumal Nayanar's Acharya Hridayam
- Vedanta Desikan's Rahasyatraya Sara
- Vedanta Desikan's Pradhana Satakam
- Vedanta Desikan's Sankalpa Suryodaya
- Vedanta Desikan's Nyaya Siddhanjana
- Vedanta Desikan’s Abhaya Pradhana Sara
- Vedanta Desikan’s Rahasya Ratnavali Hridayam
- Manavala Mamunigal’s commentary on Pillai Lokacharya’s Mumukshupadi
- Srinivasa Dasa's Yatindra Mata Dipika
- Buchchi Venkatacharya's Vedanta Karikavali

Advaita philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Gaudapada's Mandukya Karika
- Gaudapada's Samkhya Karika Bhashya
- Adi Shankaracharya's Vishnu Sahasranama Bhashya
- Adi Shankaracharya's Vivekachudamani
- Adi Shankaracharya's Upadesa Sahasri
- Adi Shankaracharya's Vakya Vritti
- Adi Shankaracharya's Panchikaranam
- Adi Shankaracharya's Yoga Sutra Vivarana
- Adi Shankaracharya's Prashnottara Ratnamalika
- Adi Shankaracharya's Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha
- Padmapada's Panchapadika
- Mandana Mishra's Sphota Siddhi
- Sureshwaracharya's Manasollasa Vartika
- Sureshwaracharya's Pranava Vartika
- Vachaspati Mishra's Bhamati
- Vachaspati Mishra's Tattva Kaumudi
- Vidyaranya's Sarva Darshana Sangraha
- Vidyaranya's Panchadasi
- Vidyaranya's Pranava Mimamsa
- Vidyaranya's Jivanmukti Viveka
- Vidyaranya's Vivarana Prameya Sangraha
- Sri Harsha's Khandana Khanda Khadya
- Vedottama Bhattaraka's Tantra Shuddha
- Sadananda's Vedanta Sara
- Appayya Dikshitar's Siddhantalesha Sangraha
- Narayana Tirtha's Samkhya Chandrika
- Dharmaraja Adhvarindra's Vedanta Paribhasa

Purva Mimamsa philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Shabara Swami's Mimamsa Sutra Bhashya
- Kumarila Bhatta's Shloka Vartika
- Kumarila Bhatta's Tantra Vartika
- Parthasarathi Mishra's Shastra Dipika
- Laugakshi Bhaskara's Artha Sangraha
- Apadeva's Mimamsa Nyaya Prakasha
- Krishnayajvan's Mimamsa Paribhasa
- Narayana Bhattar's Manameyodaya

Shaiva Siddhanta philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Tirumular's Tirumantiram
- Sadyojyoti's Tattvatraya Nirnaya
- Bhatta Ramakantha's commentary on the Tattvatraya Nirnaya
- Aghorasiva's commentary on the Tattvatraya Nirnaya
- Sadyojyoti's Paramoksha Nirasa Karika
- Bhatta Ramakantha's commentary on the Paramoksha Nirasa Karika
- Aghorasiva's Kriyakramadyotika
- Meykandar's commentary on the Shiva Jnana Bodham
- Arulnandi Shivacharya's Shiva Jnana Siddhiyar
- Shivagrayogi's commentary on the Shiva Jnana Bodham
- Appayya Dikshitar's Shivadvaita Nirnaya
- Appayya Dikshitar's Sikharinimala
- Appayya Dikshitar's Shiva Tattva Viveka

Kashmiri Shaivite philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Vasugupta's Shiva Sutras
- The Virupaksha Panchashika
- Kallata Bhatta's Spanda Karika
- Somananda's Shivadrishti
- Utpaladeva's commentary on the Shivadrishti
- Utpaladeva's Ishwara Pratyabhijna Karika
- Abhinavagupta's Tantraloka
- Abhinavagupta's Paramarthasara
- Yogaraja's commentary on the Paramarthasara

Shakta philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Bhaskararaya's Lalita Sahasranana Bhashya
- Bhaskararaya's Varivasya Rahasya
- Punyananda's Kamakalavilasa

Samkhya philosophical works not already mentioned:

- Kapila's Tattva Samasa
- Narendra's commentary on the Tattva Samasa
- Ishwara Krishna's Samkhya Karika
- Yukti Dipika
- Paramartha's Chinese version of the lost Samkhya Saptati
- Gaudapada's Samkhya Karika Bhashya
- Vachaspati Mishra's Samkhya Tattva Kaumudi
- Narayana Tirtha's Samkhya Chandrika
- Aniruddha's Samkhya Sutra Vritti
- Vijnanabhikshu's Samkhya Sutra Bhashya

Miscellaneous Works:

- Adiseshan's Paramarthasara
- Bhartrihari's Vakyapadiya
- Haritayana's Tripura Rahasya
- Yoga Vasishta
- Chandramati's Dashapadartha Shastra
- Jayanta Bhatta's Nyayamanjari

I'm probably leaving a ton of things out, and I'm intentionally leaving out hymns by Acharyas and modern scholarly works I've read, since this is already running long. And this will probably be hopelessly out of date by the time other people read this.  In any case, if anyone is interested in reading any of these texts, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Since there is a possibility of hopeless outdatedness, have you read Swami Deshikan's Yadavabhyudayam?

Comment: Also where do you get Vishnudharmottara?

Comment: @Surya No, I haven't read the Yadavabhyudayam; I haven't come across an English translation of it.  Concerning the Vishnudharmottara Purana, there's a translation published by the Indira Gandhi National Centre for the Arts.  I can try to find it again.  And yeah, it continues to be out of date, I need to add a whole bunch of Samkhya, Nyaya, and Vaisheshika works to the list.

Comment: @Surya I may provide more links later, but on a quick Google search I found two books which translate a part of the Vishnudharmottara Purana: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.127780 https://archive.org/details/vishnudharmottar031493mbp

Comment: Thanks for the links! So - there is a Sanskrit version of Yadavabhyudayam available?

Comment: @Surya I just found Vedanta Desikan's Yadavbhyudayam along with the Shaivite philosopher Appaya Dikshitar's commentary on it in Sanskrit.  Here are all the volumes of it. Cantos 1-4: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367344 Cantos 5-8: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.496374 Cantos 9-12: https://archive.org/stream/TFIC_ASI_Books/YadavabhyudayaVol.3 Cantos 13-18: https://archive.org/stream/TFIC_ASI_Books/YadavabhyudayaVol.1 Cantors 19-24: https://archive.org/stream/TFIC_ASI_Books/YadavabhyudayaVol.2 Note that the volume numbers make no sense.

Comment: Can you please share link for - Jayanta Bhatta's Nyayamanjari PDf .:-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Sure: https://archive.org/details/NyayaManjariOfJayantaBhatta By the way, Jayanta Bhatta is one of the few philosophers who belonged to the actual Nyaya school rather than belonging to some other school like Navyanyaya (like Udayana) or Vedanta (like Vachaspati Mishra) and just writing about Nyaya from the outside.

Comment: Oh ,Ok ,Nice info. and very thanks :-)

Comment: This is really excellent list. Can you kindly convert each scripture name into hyperlink. Then it will be great ready reference

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "if you see any texts in my answer above that interest you, tell me and I can give you links" - can u pls be kind enough to provide links in your answer itself if u hv them? This might help other users a lot.. Thanks :)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar That’s by Pillai Lokacharya, not Ramanujacharya, but yes I’ve read it.  By the way, here are Ramanujacharya’s nine works: the Sri Bhashya, the Vedanta Sara, the Vedanta Dipa, the Bhagavad Gita Bhashya, thd Vedartha Sangraha, the Sharanagati Gadya, the Sri Ranga Gadya, the Vaikuntha Gadya, and the Nitya Grantha.  I’ve read all of them except the Nitya Grantha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan ji would you recommend reading Vedas in English or Hindi/any other language in Devanagari script closer to Sanskrit?As i feel after reading some of the english translations all of its philosophical value and essence is lost because often the ppl who have translated the texts compare/translate vedic terms in the light of christian theology which heavily distorts the meaning....

Comment: Wow. This takes up half the page :)

Answer (score 13):

I've read 13 [Mukhya Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukhya_Upanishads) which are:

(Have read with Adi Shankaracharya Bhashya):

1. Īśā (ईश)
2. Kena (केन)
3. Kaṭha (कठ)
4. Praṣna (प्रश्न)
5. Muṇḍaka (मुण्डक)
6. Māṇḍūkya (माण्डुक्य) with Gaudpad Karika (गौड़पाद करिका)
7. Aitareya (ऐतरेय)
8. Taittirīya (तैत्तिरीय)
9. Shvetashvatara (श्वेताश्वतर)
10. Chāndogya (छान्दोग्य)

(Without Bhashya):

11. Bṛhadāraṇyaka (बृहदारण्यक)
12. Kauṣītaki (कौषीतकि)
13. Maitrāyaṇīya (मैत्रायणीय)

---

PrakaranaGrantha (प्रकरणग्रंथ) of Adi Shankaracharya:

1. Vivekachudamani (विवेकचूडामणि)
2. ShataShloki (शतश्लोकि)
3. AatmaBodhha (आत्मबोध)
4. TattvaBodhha (तत्त्वबोध)
5. Advaitaanubhuti (अद्वैतानुभूति)
6. Aparokshaanubhuti (अपरोक्षानुभूति)
7. Sarva Vedanta Sidhaanta Saar Sangrah (सर्व वेदांत सिद्धान्त सार संग्रह)

---

Veda Samhitas:

- Sāmaveda Saṃhitā
  (सामवेद संहिता)

---

[Darshana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy) Sutras:

- Brahma Sutra (ब्रह्मसूत्र) [Interpretation by Harikrishna Das Goyandka]
- Yog Sutras (योगसुत्र​) of Patanjali
- Vyasa Bhashya on Yogasutras of Patanjali
- Rajayoga (राजयोग) by Swami Vivekananda
- Sankhya Karika (सांख्यकारिका) of IshwarKrishna

---

Other texts:

- Shirmad Bhagavad Gita (श्रीमद्भगवद्गीता)
- Rama Gita (रामगीता)
- Prasthana Bheda of Madhusudana Sarasvati
- [Adi Shankaracharya Jeevan Charitra](https://archive.org/details/ShankaracharyaJivanCharitra)
- [Sri Ramanujacharya Jeevan Charitra](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-shriRamanujacharya.kaJeevan.charit)

---

Some parts of following texts:

- Bhagavata Purana
- Yoga Vashishtha Ramayana
- Works (speeches) of Swami Vivekananda

---

Ongoing (descending order of priority):

1. Nirukta of Yaskacharya
2. Adi Shankaracharya Bhashya on Brhama Sutra

Future plan (descending order of priority):

1. Vijnana Bhairava Tantra
2. Shanti Parva of Mahabharata
3. Rigveda Samhita
4. Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha of Adi Shankaracharya <sup>[image]</sup>

Comment: Awesome to know! :) Never heard of Ram Gita before.

Comment: @AmitSaxena Adyatma Ramayana, Uttar Kand, Pancham Sarga is known as Rama Gita.

Comment: I like that "wanted gif"

Comment: @Pandya Like that flashing gif. And from that i think we also can ask a question "What Texts You Want"  :-)

Comment: Time to remove that "Wanted" Gif. https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.311086

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thanks. Btw, it would be more useful if I find Hindi translation.

Answer (score 10):

I have read the following:

Bhagavada Gita

Narada Bhakti Sutras

Patanjali Yoga Sutras

Ashtavakra Gita

[Yoga Vashishtha](http://estudantedavedanta.net/The-Supreme-Yoga-Swami-Venkatesananda.pdf)

Kenopanishada

Kathopanishada

Amongst other things, I am currently reading the Vaisheshika Sutras, Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra and Panini's Ashtadhyayi.

Comment: in case if you have links for those, please add it too. So anyone seeing this post can quickly open and read it and get more involved

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have read these through books. I am not aware of the specific online versions of the books that I have read, except Yoga Vashishtha, which I am adding.

Answer (score 8):

I have read 6 [Mukhya Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukhya_Upanishads)

1. [Taittirīya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taittiriya_Upanishad)
2. [Māndūkya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%81%E1%B9%87%E1%B8%8D%C5%ABkya)
3. [Chāndogya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C4%81ndogya_Upani%E1%B9%A3ad)
4. [Bṛhadāraṇyaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%B9%9Bhad%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87yaka)
5. [Praṣna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prashnopanishad)
6. [Katha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katha_Upanishad)

Answer (score 7):

Namaskar,

I belong to the sAmaveda, and this is the Veda that I am always studying. Slowly, I am trying to memorise the saMhitA, and work on it a little each day. I am also from the nimbArka sampradAya, so many of the texts I have read are related to this. From the rest of the karmakANDa of the vedas, I have read:

- RRigveda: saMhitA, aitareya brAhmaNa, kauShItaki brAhmaNa, aitareya AraNyaka, shA~NkhAyanAraNyaka
- sAmaveda: pa~nchaviMsha brAhmaNa, talavakAra AraNyaka, gautama dharmasUtra, gobhila gRRihyasUtra
- yajurveda: mAdhyandina saMhitA, shatapatha brAhmaNa
- atharvaveda: shaunakIya saMhitA, gopatha brAhmaNa

From the j~nAnakANDa:

- 13 main upaniShads, yoga upaniShads, sAmanya upaniShads, vaiShnava upaniShads
- vedAntasUtra with vedAntapArijAtasaurabha and vedAntakaustubha commentaries, by mimbArka and shrInivAsa respechtively
- gIta with tattvaprakAshikA commentary of keshava kAshmIri

other sUtras and purANic literature:

- yoga sUtra with vyasa commentary
- haThayogapradIpikA
- sAMkhyakArikA
- mImAMsA sUtra
- nArada bhakti sUtra
- sanatkumAra saMhitA
- nArada pa~ncharAtra
- shANDilya bhakti sUtra
- bhAgavata purANa
- viShNu purANa
- parts from the garuDa purANa
- parts from the padma purAna
- rAmacharitamAnasa
- summary version of mahAbhAratam

I have also read gIta govindam, nArAyanIyam and kRRiShNa karNAmRRita

Secondary texts about my sampradAya that I have read:

[Doctrine](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.939), [Philosophy 1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.408344), [2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.204859/page/n201), [Philosophical Tradition](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/darshana/vedanta/nimbaraka-philosophical-tradition) [History](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-3/d/doc7615.html), [Bhedabheda, Dvaitadvaita](https://archive.org/details/encyclopediaofindianphilosophyvolume15bhedabhedaanddvaitadvaitasystemsagarwalm.m.karlpotterh._928_w/), [Jiva Brahman Relation](http://ir.amu.ac.in/108/1/T%20908.pdf), [Radha Krishna's Vedantic Debut](https://era.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1842/26018/Ramnarace2015.pdf), [Vedanta Kaustubha Prabha](http://ir.amu.ac.in/4345/1/T%204201.pdf), [Sharanagati](https://archive.org/details/saranamprapadyeproceedingsoftheseminaronsaranagati2007/page/n107),  [Sampradaya](https://www.academia.edu/14515642/_Nimb%C4%81rka_samprad%C4%81ya_In_Brill_s_Encyclopedia_of_Hinduism_Volume_Three_Edited_by_Knut_A_Jacobsen_and_Helene_Basu_Angelika_Malinar_Vasudha_Narayan_429_443_Leiden_Brill_2011), [Nimbarka 1](https://www.academia.edu/36489326/Nimb%C4%81rka), [2](https://archive.org/details/vaishnaviteschoolsofphilosophydrathiruvengadathan2006/page/n69) [Prediction](https://archive.org/details/the-vedic-prophecies-a-new-look-into-the-stephen-knapp/page/n217)

More sampradAya texts in Sanskrit that I have not yet been able to read, but hope to learn  in the future.

[Vedanta Commentaries](https://archive.org/details/vsnimbarka), [Siddhantasetuka, Siddhantajahnavi 1](https://archive.org/details/BrahmaSutraDvaitadvaitaDarshanChowkhambaSanskritSeries1905Pt.DamodarLalGoswami/), [2](https://archive.org/details/BrahmaSutraDvaitadvaitaDarshanIIChowkhambaSanskritSeries1906RatnaGopalBhatta), [3](https://archive.org/details/BrahmaSutrasDvaitadvaitaDarshanIIIChowkhambaSanskritSeries1927Pt.GopalSastri), [Sri Krishnastavaraja with Shrutyantasuradruma and Shrutisiddhantamanjari commentaries](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.554036/), [Laghustavaraja Stotram with commentary](https://archive.org/details/KramaDeepikaOfKashmirikaKeshavaBhattaFasciliusIIIFeb1919No254ChowkhambaSanskritSeries/page/n65/mode/2up), [Siddhantasangraha](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313624), [Dasasloki with Laghumanjusa](https://archive.org/details/DashashlokiNimbarka), [Ratnamanjusha](https://archive.org/details/GxCx_vedanta-ratna-manjusha-shri-bhagawat-purushottama-acharya), [Kramadipika 1](https://archive.org/details/KramaDeepikaOfKasmirikaKeshavaBhattaFasciliusIChowkhambaSanskritSeries.pdf), [2](https://archive.org/details/KramaDeepikaOfKashmirikaKeshavaBhattaFasciliusIIAug1917No236ChowkhambaSanskritSeries), [3](https://archive.org/details/KramaDeepikaOfKeshvaBhattKashmirakaNo2361917ChowkambaSanskritSeries), [Transliteration](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/corpustei/transformations/html/sa_kezavakAzmIri-kramadIpikA.htm), [Purusha Sukta commentary](https://archive.org/details/KuOb_purush-sukta-with-nimbark-bhashya-of-kamal-krishna-by-dhundhiraj-shastri-series-/page/n3/mode/2up), [Vishnunamartha](https://archive.org/details/vs_shukasudhi), [Svadharmamritasindhu](https://archive.org/details/sva_dharmamrita_sindhu), [prAtaHsmaraNam](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/kRRiShNaprAtaHsmaraNam.itx) [rAdhAvarAShTakaM](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/rAdhAvarAShTakam.itx), [Mantra Rahasya Sodasi](http://grantha.jiva.org/index.php?show=entry&e_no=627)

Comment: Wow..too many text related to Vedas !!

Answer (score 6):

I have read following books, some complete some incomplete.

- Rig Veda
- Sama Vda
- Valmiki Ramayana
- Ramacharitmanasa by Goswami Tulasias
- Mahabharata
- Vishnu Purana
- Shiva Purana
- Devi Bhagavata Purana
- Shrimada Bhagavata Purana
- Padma Purana
- Skanda Purana
- Vayu Purana
- Agni Purana
- Linga Purana
- Marakandeya Purana
- Matsya Purana
- Nrisingha Purana
- Manu Smriti
- Parashara Smriti
- Vishnu Smriti
- Apastamba Dharma Sutra
- Gautama Dharma Sutra
- Vashishtha Dharma Sutra
- Baudhayana Dharma Sutra
- Bhagavad Gita
- Pandava Gita

Comment: Nicely covered the various categories!

Comment: One minor correction: it should be Apastamba Dharma Sutras, not Apastamba Dharma Shastra, and similarly for Gautama, Baudhayana, and Vasishta.  They are Dharmashastra texts, but their actual names are Dharma Sutras because they're in aphoristic format.  By the way, two other Dharmashastra texts you might want to read are the Yagnavalkya Smriti and the Vaikhanasa Dharma Sutras.  I can give you links if you're interested.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks, corrected the information. Yes please provide me the links.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Here is the Yagnavalkya Smriti: https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj And here's the Vaikhanasa Dharma Sutras: http://gdurl.com/dQOe/download Also, if you see any texts in my answer above that interest you, tell me and I can give you links.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks again and sure I will ask for.

Answer (score 5):

1. Mahabharata (in bits and pieces)

   - Bhagavad Gita (in detail)

Comment: You can also mention the various commentaries (if any) you've referred on BG.

Comment: @Pandya, no I have just read translations. First it was from ISKCON (short while), then mainly from Gitapress and lately from Gambhirananda. Due to online sources, we can also translate ourselves with some help.

Comment: Shrimad Bhagavata Purana is also very interesting purana to read and not much bigger either. Try to read Gita Press version. I am sure you will like it very well.

Answer (score 5):

I have read following texts completely:

1. Shiva Sutras by Jaideva Singh
2. Spandakarika by Jaideva Singh
3. Ishavasya Upanishad
4. I like **Ramayana** most among all itihasa. And it was one of the subject during my primary education, that's where I read it fully. But it might have missed many events which would be present in Valmiki Ramayana.
5. Not the actual texts, but I have watched Bhagwat Gita part from old Mahabharata serial.
6. Kaularnava Tantra

Currently I am reading:

1. Vijanbhairava Tantra
2. Ramayana

Pipelined texts:

1. Bhagwat Gita in the light of Kashmiri Shaivism
2. Remaining mukhya Upanishad.

Answer (score 4):

I have read the following scriptures either partially or completely:

1. Valmiki Ramayana
2. Srimad Bhagavatam
3. Vishnu Purana
4. Apastamba Dharma Sutra
5. Chaitanya Charitamrita
6. Narayana Upanishad
7. Kali-Saṇṭāraṇa Upanishad
8. Kalki Purana
9. Bhagavad Gita (with the commentary of Jagadguru Ramanujacharya)
10. Brahma Samhita
11. Ramcharitmanas
12. Parashara Smriti
13. Garbha Upanishad
14. Vishnu Sahasranamam
15. Kena Upanishad (with the commentary of Ranga Ramanuja)
16. Garuda Purana
17. Vairagya Sandipani
18. Sri Krishna Chaitanya Maha Kavya
19. Isha Upanishad (with the commentary of Vedanta Desikan)
20. The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna
21. Tales and Parables of Sri Ramakrishna
22. Vishnu Tantra
23. Satvata Tantra

Comment: Oh, you read Vedanta Desikan's Isha Upanishad Bhashya? That's great!  You can go multiple directions from there.  I can give you links to other works of Vedanta Desikan.  And I can give you links to other Sri Vaishnava Upanishad Bhashyas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks! That'll be deeply appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have fully read the following texts

1. Bhagavad Gita
2. Patanjali Yoga Sutras
3. Katha Upanishad
4. Isha Upanishad

Read these partially

1. Odia Bhagavad Purana by Atibadi Jagannatha Das
2. Odia Mahabharata by Sarala Das
3. Valmiki Ramayana

And I am currently reading

1. Kena Upanishad

Answer (score 2):

I became interested in philosophy in college days.

Having studied in Bengal, I studied two major sects of Bengal.

1. RamaKrishna sect with biographies of RamaKrishna and vivekananda and some other works like Raja Yoga etc...
2. Chaitanya sect with biographies of Chaitanya and primary works of Gaudiyas like six sandarbhas etc.. and some ISKCON books.
3. Some Upanishads and a bit of brahma sutras.
4. Had interest to study Shaktism, but I passed out by then.
5. Bhagavad-Gita
6. A bit of Bhagavata-purana. But since six Sandarbhas are nothing but explanations of bhagavatam, I can say I studied most of the bhagavatam though not sequentially.
7. Brahma samhita.

Then something about other religions from internet sources.
A bit about other sects as well.

Seeing the host of contradictory claims by each sects, I lost interest in all these though I have good knowledge of Gaudiya Vaishnavism and RamaKrishna mission.

I also read books like 'God Delusion' and many youtube videos of Sam Harris and others.

As such I don't subscribe to any of the things now and just do whatever feels good.

Comment: I am much shocked and surprised to know that after reading so much of the wonderful literature especially of two sects, you lost interest seeing the contradiction. Do not you feel that these contradictions are only apparent?

Answer (score 2):

Bhagavad Gita As It Is

Srimad Bhagavatam with commentary by Srila Prabhupada(only 3 cantos)

Isha Upanishad with commentary of Srila Prabhupada.

Teachings of Lord Chaitanya

Teachings of Prahlada

Easy journey to other planets

Ramayana the Game of Life series first 2 books.

Nectar of Instruction

Second chance

Demystifying Reincarnation by Chaitanya Charan Das

Oh My God Reanswering the questions by Chaitanya Charan Das.

Answer (score 2):

I do have read quite a number of scriptures, mostly online. The only texts that I possess in hardcopy form are

1. *Śrimadbhagavadgītā*
2. *Devīmāhatmya*
3. *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Kathāmṛta*

Outside these 3 books, other knowledge would mostly come in the form of storybooks (which I don't consider to be worth mentionable in this site, except for the condensed version of the Rāmāyaṇa & Mahābhārata by Upendrakiśora Rāyachaudhurī in Bengali).

After joining Quora, I realised the greatness of the Sanskrit canonical texts. At that time, I acquired the softcopy of these texts

1. *Devībhāgavata Purāṇa* English translation by Svāmī Vijñanānanda
2. *Kālikā Purāṇa* Bengali transliteration published by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna

After discovering Internet Archive & a quick browse through Wikipedia, I got in contact with the following texts

1. *Vṛhaddharma Purāṇa* Bengali transliteration published by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna
2. *Devī Purāṇa* Bengali transliteration published by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna
3. *Mahānirvāṇa Tantra* Bengali transliteration published by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna
4. *Garga Saṁhita* Bengali transliteration published by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna
5. *Devībhāgavata Purāṇa* in Sanskrit with Nilakaṇṭha's tīkā, published by Khemraj Srikrishnadas Press
6. *Devīmāhātmya* with Nāgojībhaṭṭa's commentary & Bengali transliteration by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna
7. *Shiva Purāṇa* English translation by Motilal Banarasidass
8. *Skanda Purāṇa* English translation published by Motilal Banarasidass
9. *Nārada Purāṇa* English translation published by Motilal Banarasidass
10. *Vāmana Purāṇa* English transliteration
11. *Tripurā Rahasya - Māhātmya khaṇḍa* Hindi transliteration published by Chaukhamba Surbharati Prakashan
12. *Śrividyārṇava Tantra* Hindi transliteration published by Chaukhamba Surbharati Prakashan
13. *Śaradatilaka Tantra* with Rāghavabhaṭṭa's commentary & Hindi transliteration published by Chaukhamba Sanskrit Pratisthana
14. *Mantra Mahodadhi* with Mahīdhara's commentary & Hindi transliteration published by Chaukhamba Sanskrit Pratisthana
15. *Mantra Maharnava* in Sanskrit published by Khemraj Srikrishnadas Press
16. *Meru Tantra* in Sanskrit published by Khemraj Srikrishnadas Press
17. *Vṛhattantrasāra* Bengali transliteration published by Rasikamohāna Chaṭṭopādhyāya
18. *Prāṇatoṣaṇī Tantra* in Sanskrit
19. *Śāktānandataraṅgiṇī* in Sanskrit
20. *Mahākālasamhitā* in Sanskrit (except Vol I) published Rastriya Sanskrit Sansthana
21. *Āgamatattvavilāsa* Hindi transliteration published by Chaukhamba Surbharati Prakashana
22. *Nirṇayasindhu* Hindi transliteration published by Khemraj Srikrishnadas Press
23. *Smṛtitattva* in Sanskrit published by Paṇḍita Jīvānanda Vidyāsāgara
24. *Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa* English transliteration published by Parimal Publications
25. *Mahābhāgavata Upapurāṇa* Hindi transliteration published by Gita Press
26. *Harivaṁśa* Hindi transliteration published by Gita Press
27. *Nārada Pañcarātra - Jñānāmṛtasāra* Bengali transliteration
28. *Balabhadra Pañcaṅga* - a Devanāgarī Sanskrit handwriiten manuscript preserved at the library of Jammu's Raghunatha Mandira

Partially read texts include

1. *Viṣṇudharmottara Purāṇa* in Sanskrit published by Khemraj Srikrishnadas Press
2. *Padma Purāṇa* English translation published by Motilal Banarasidass
3. *Garuṛa Purāṇa* English translation
4. *Matsya Purāṇa* Bengali transliteration by Paṇḍita Pañcānana Tarkaratna
5. *Kūrma Purāṇa* Hindi transliteration published by Gita Press
6. *Brahma Purāṇa* English translation published by Motilal Banarasidass
7. *Haribhaktivilāsa* with Sanātana Gosvāmī's commentary & Hindi transliteration published by Paṇḍita Haridāsa Śāstrī
8. *Iśanaśivagurudevapaddhati* in Sanskrit
9. *Śrimadbhagavadgītā* with English transliteration of Ādi Śaṅkarācārya's commentary

Both lists will continue to grow in future.

Comment: Woah! That's a long list..

Comment: Thanks @TheLittleNaruto for the compliment.