# What scriptural books make up your impressive collections?

Tags: discussion, community, scripture

As discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/793/277), scriptures are the most authentic source of knowledge as per our Acharyas. Our site has many users who are well versed in several Shastras. To know more about such users and popular texts, we also have a question [Which texts have you read?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/573/277).

Now with a purpose of keeping the encouragement among the [community](/questions/tagged/community) users, I am posting this post (partially ideated by [TheLittleNaruto](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/647/thelittlenaruto)) know the mode and practice of reading texts, text collections like library etc. being followed by the dedicated members.

So, let's discuss!

- How do you read the text? (Physical Copy, Soft Copy, Audio Books etc..)
- **Do you have your collection or library to share with us? Post some images in your answers**
- Although we have a thread [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/277) by [TheDestroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) where we have a good collection of some sources, if you have some recommendations on publications or another good resources then you can also discuss them here.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for posting this question!! I do want to share my collection. Tbh it is not like too many but a very few. I am sure, there must be many users having way better collection than mine.

Also, I prefer reading hard-copy because my daily work involves uses of computer and mobile devices a lot, So I just avoid reading soft copies.

So here is few snaps of my library:
[image]

[image]

**Picture 1:** *(Sequence:From top to bottom)*

1. [Shiva Sutras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24959/647) - by Shree Jaideva Singh ji
2. Kaularnava Tantra - by Ram Kumar Rai
3. Spandakarika - by Shree Jaideva Singh ji
4. Vijnanabhairava Tantra - by Shree Jaideva Singh ji
5. [Parshuram Kalpa Sutram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38570/647)
6. Srimad Valmiki Ramayana Part 1 - Geeta Press
7. Srimad Valmiki Ramayana Part 2 - Geeta Press

**Picture 2:**

1. To the left: Shiva Drishti - a philosophical text by Acharya Somananda from Kashmir Shaivism
2. To the right: Shree Shiva Stotravalli - a devotional text by Acharya Utpaladeva from Kashmir Shaivism

Comment: Thanks for sharing the image. Nice to see the Tantra / Kashmiri Shaiva texts

Comment: @Pandya I hope you noticed pks too. Note that there is no authentic version of pks written ever. This version is just a failed attempt if I can put it that way. :-)

Comment: Nice collection! I'd be interested in hearing your thoughts on the parashurama kalpa sutra. Is it insightful/enlightening/worth reading? I've heard that the writing is hard to decipher.

Comment: Check this answer: [Do we have any preaching or works of Lord Parashurama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38570/647) @CDR

Comment: @CDR the authentic version is not available and can only be learned by a competent Guru none else.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yes, I see it published by Sampurnanand Sanskrit Vishwavidyalaya.

Answer (score 5):

My collection is a lot less impressive than other people's...

actually, the only 'print' books I have are a couple of Tamil prayer books.

[image]

Only a few of the books in this image are religious- there's the Ramayana and the stories of Vikramaditya, and the two tattered books on the top of the stack are prayer books. The book without a spine on the left side is an annotated version of part of the Yajur Veda.

The bulk of my actual collection is in PDFs. The reason for this is that I like to annotate my texts, but I feel bad about doing that in a truly paper book.

So here is a boring screenshot:

> [image]

I once had a lot more, but the USB stick they were saved on recently went bad, so all my documents and annotations were lost :(
I've had to rebuild my collection. The texts I have right now are:

> **Hindi**
>
> - Sama Veda
> - Gita
>
> **Purana**
>
> - Periya Puranam
> - Siva Purana
> - Nilamata Purana
> - Narada Purana
>
> **Shankaracharya**
>
> - Atma Bodha
> - Vivekachudamani
>
> **Tamil**
>
> - Ramayanam
> - Mahabaratam
>
> **Upanishad**
>
> - Isha Upanishad
> - Katho Upanishad
> - Svetsvarata Upanishad
>
> **Veda**
>
> - Rig Veda
> - Sama Veda
> - Taittiriya Samhita

Answer (score 5):

#### This is the collection I do have at my home!

[image: Granthalayah]

First I will mention the name of all books shown in above picture and then will dicuss about the history of this Sangraha.

### 1<sup>st</sup> Row

| Left | Center | Right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **(Work of Saint Tulasidas & Yoga Vashishtha)** | **(Spiritual Treatises)** | **(Upanishads & Darshanas)** |
| ▪️Low of Karma ▪️Lomas Bhusundi Samvad ▪️Hariras ▪️Hanuman Janjira ▪️Rama Tatva Darshana ▪️Maanas Rahasya ▪️Kalyan Ramayana ▪️Tulasidas Vinaya Patrika ▪️Barve Ramayana ▪️Ramashvamegha ▪️Hariras ▪️Bhagavad Gita As It Is ▪️Hanuman Natakdhara ▪️Yaga Vashishtha (Part 2) Sastu Sahitya ▪️Kalyan Yoga Vashishthank ▪️Adbhuta Ramayana ▪️Digitized Version Print of Yoga Vashishtha (Part-1) | ▪️Vivekachudamani Sastu Sahitya ▪️Vivekachudamani Gitapress ▪️Jnaneshwari Gita (Gujarati Version) ▪️Taranga authored by Nischaldasji published by LaxmiVenkatedh Press, Mumbai) ▪️Gita Dohan (Tattvarth Deepika authroed by Krishnatmaji Maharaj) ▪️Gita Gudhartha Deepika authored by Chiddhanand) ▪️Aatma Purana ▪️Kalyaan Sadhananka ▪️Aadhyatma Ramayana ▪️Peepacharya Darshana | ▪️SaamaVeda ▪️Yogasutras of Patanjali (Sankhya Yoga) ▪️Saundarya Lahiri ▪️Sanatan Dharma Tatva Sangraha ▪️Vaidika Sukta Sangrah ▪️Stotra Ratnavali ▪️Divya Sandesha of Veda ▪️Dairy 1 ▪️Dairy 2 ▪️Niruktam ▪️Vyasa Bhashya on Yoga Sutras ▪️Vedanta Darshana ▪️Chhandogya Upanishad ▪️Brihadaranyaka Upanishad ▪️Ishadi 9 Upanishads ▪️Upanishad Vidya by BhaanDev ▪️Shankar Bhashya of Brahma Sutra |

### 2<sup>nd</sup> Row

| Left | Center | Right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Forefathers works** | **Various editions of Rama Charit Manas** | **Puranas & Itihasas** |
| ▪️Yoga Vashishta Ancient Copies from probably late 19th century or early 20th century ▪️Dada's Dairies (1970s - 2010s) | ▪️Ramacharita Manasa (Hanuman Das Poddar) ▪️ Tulasikrit Ramayana (Khemraj Krishnadas - Venkatesh Press Mumbai) ▪️ Ramacharita Manas Three Parts (Gitapress) ▪️ Ramacharita Manasa (Rambalakdas Vaishnav Printing Press) ▪️ Tulasikrit Ramayana (Gujarati Version) ▪️ Kalyaan Raama Anka | ▪️Shiva Purana - Harihar Prakashan ▪️Shiva Purana - Rajaram Govindram ▪️Kalyaan Jyotishanka ▪️Kalyaana Ganesha Anka (Gitapress) ▪️Devi Bhagavat Purana (Gujarati) ▪️Srimad Bhagavat Purana (2 parts) Gitapress ▪️Valmiki Ramayana (2 Parts) Gitapress |

### 3<sup>rd</sup> Row

| Left | Center | Right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vivekanand Granthamala (10 Khandas) i.e Complete Works of Swami Vivekamanda in Gujarati Published by Ram Krishna Aashrama, Rajkot, Gujarat in 10 parts. | ▪️Few books belong to Swadhyaya Pariwar and published by Sat Vichar Darshan ▪️ Misc. books realted to various Vratas and Daily Rituals | Those are not really Mangos it's just box of Mangos. It contains yet more miscellaneous books - some are historical books and some are stories for childern (to be transparent, need to open the box to get the exact details) |

There are still few more books which are placed outside of this collection and couple of books are missing which I have given to relatives for reading.

---

#### History of this Sangrah:

*Grandfather*

- My Grandfather got some books from forefathers and he preserved many of them and brought several books to the home. The Yoga Vashishtha Ramayana copies which are placed `vertically` at the `left side in the second row` and some books published by printing press in Mumbai are among those which I have received from forefathers.
- He used to study various versions and editions of Ramayana. He used to chant and preach various stories from Tulasikrit Ramayana and Yoga Vashishtha Ramayana. He also brought some new books like Kalyana's Ankas, Adhyatma Ramayana, works of Tulasidas etc. During his time, he has wrote many dairies covering some important and mysterious topics from Shashtras. His diaries are visible in above image (placed `horizontally at the left side in the second raw`). Apart from that, with an effort of decades he extracted the voluminous Yoga Vashishtha and wrote his own books on it, named "Yoga Vashishtha Saaransha". His writings are later on digitized by my father.

*Father*

- My father, finding that many books are getting damaged by termite, did the great job of preserving as much books from my grandfather's time as he can, however we still lost several books damaged by termite. Most of the books placed at `left and at center portion both in first & second rows` are among them!
- Books on Puranas, which are placed `at right side of the 2nd row` are brought by my mother.

*Me*

- Now, coming to my own collection! It is placed at `the right side of the 1st row`. As I've disclosed in [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/578/277), I am interested in Upanishads and Yoga. So most of the books fall in that category. I prefer reading physical copy only as that only gives a feeling like reading the real *Granthah!* Some of them belonging to Gitapress Publication are bought during the journey to Haridwar & Mathura. Vyasha Bhashya on Yoga Sutras of Patanjali, Adi Shankaracharya's Bhashya on Brahma Sutra and Niruktam are bought through website of Chukhamba publication. That samaveda book is bought from Banaras Hindu University, Varanasi.
- Since I like treatises on spiritual philosophy, I have kept books (which I have received from grandfather collection) together near to my collection i.e placed at `center part of first row`.

How should I keep this continue and preserve ancient books from getting damaged?

Comment: That's like a big library.. anyway it's Pandya boi's collection. So expected!

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- This is primary version of the answer, under construction and will be updated with more information!

---

Thank you @TheLittleNaruto for inviting me to answer this question.

Honestly speaking, my hardcopy collection doesn't consists of what would qualify as scriptures to some people here. It mostly falls under the category of 'biographies & memoirs of saints'. However I do maintain a good online collection. Here are the screenshots

[image]

From right to left :

1. *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭher Ādikathā* - a history of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* from it's founding in 1886 until it's shifting to the current premises on *Belur* in 1899, written in Bengali by my *guru Svamī Prabhānanda*, who was one of the 5 Vice-presidents of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission from 2012 until his death this year.
2. *Brahmānandacarita* - a biography of *Svāmī Brahmānanda*, a direct disciple of *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva*, the 1st President of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission (from 1901 until his death in 1922) & my *parāparaguru*, written by my *guru* in Bengali.
3. *Sāradānandacarita* - a biography of *Svāmī Sāradānanda*, a direct disciple of *Śri Śri Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva* & the 1st General Secretary of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission (from 1901 until his death in 1927), written in Bengali by my *guru*, (who had also served as Assistant General Secretary in 1984-1995 & General Secretary in 2007-2012)
4. *Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇer Antyalīlā* Vol 2 - a memoir of the last days of *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva* in Bengali compiled by my *guru*
5. *Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇer Antyalīlā* Vol 1
6. *Svāmī Sāradānander Jibanī* - a biography, collection of memoirs & letters of *Svāmī Sāradānanda* in Bengali written by *Brahmacārī Akṣayacaitanya*
7. *Amṛtarūpa Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa* - a book written by my *guru* in Bengali
8. *Ānandarūpa Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa* - a book written by my *guru* in Bengali
9. *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Līlāprasaṅga* Vol 2 - a biography of *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva* written in Bengali by *Svāmī Sāradānanda*
10. *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Līlāprasaṅga* Vol 1
11. *Smṛtir Āloye Svāmījī* - a collection of memoirs of *Svāmī Vivekānanda* in Bengali compiled by *Svāmī Pūrṇātmānanda*, currently the head of the *Ḍhākā* branch of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission.
12. *Śrī Śrī Māyer Kathā* - a collection of the sayings of the Holy Mother of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha*  & Mission, *Śrī Śrī Sāradāmaṇi Debī*, consort of *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva*
13. *Prācīna Sādhuder Kathā* Vol 1 - a collection of memoirs of some of the senior monks of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission in Bengali compiled by *Svāmī Cetanānanda*, currently the head of the St. Louis branch of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* in Missouri, USA
14. *Prācīna Sādhuder Kathā* Vol 2
15. *Juganāyāka Bibekānanda* Vol 3 - a biography of *Svāmī Vivekānanda* in Bengali composed by *Svāmī Gambhirānanda, the 11th President of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission from 1985 until his death in 1988
16. *Juganāyāka Bibekānanda* Vol 2
17. *Juganāyāka Bibekānanda* Vol 1
18. *Tantrokta Nityapūjā Paddhati O Rahasyapūjā Paddhati* - a book on *Tāntrika* rites in Bengali composed by *Jaganmohana Tarkālaṅkāra* (1827-1898), a renowned *Tāntrasádhaka* of Calcutta
19. *Svāmī Śaṅkarānanda* - a biography of *Svāmī Śaṅkarānanda*, the 7th President of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission from 1951 until his death in 1962 & my *paramaguru*
20. *Śatarūpe Sāradā* - a collection of memoirs of *Śrī Śrī Sāradāmaṇi Debī* in Bengali compiled by *Svāmī Lokeśvarānanda* of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa* Mission Institute of Culture.

[image]

Left : *Matṛidarśana* - a collection of memoirs of *Śrī Śrī Sāradāmaṇi Debī* in Bengali compiled by *Svāmī Cetanānanda*

The 4 books from the right are the 4 volumes of *Śrī Śrī Māyer Padaprānte*, a collection of memoirs of the Holy Mother *Śrī Śrī Sāradāmaṇi Debī* in Bengali compiled by *Svāmī Pūrṇātmānanda*

[image]

Right : *Paramārtha Prasaṅga* - a small booklet in Bengali on the sayings of *Svāmī Virajānanda*, the 6th President of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission from 1938 until his death in 1951

Left : 'Strive to Attain God' - a compilation of some works of *Svāmī Virajānanda* that were published in the *Prabuddha Bhārata*, the English mouthpiece of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission.

I also do possess

1. *Svāmī Saṅkarānander Galpakathā* - a Bengali memoir of *Svāmī Saṅkarānanda* composed by his personal attendant
2. *Śrī Mā Sāradā Debī* - a Bengali biography of the Holy Mother *Śrī Śrī Sāradāmaṇi Debī* composed by *Svāmī Gambhirānanda*
3. *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Kathāmṛta* - a collection of the sayings of *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva*

Here is the list of books that I downloaded

[image]
[image]
[image]

Book info

1. *Annadākalpatantra* & *Ākāśabhairavakalpa* are *Tāntrika* texts.
2. *Āgamatattvavilāsa* is a *Tāntrika nibandha* composed by *Raghunātha Tarkavāgiśa* of Eastern Bengal.
3. *Kṛtyaratnākara* is a *Smṛti* digest composed by the *Maithilī paṇḍita Caṇḍeśvara Ṭhakura*
4. *Dharmasindhu* is a *Smṛti* digest composed by the *Marāṭhi paṇḍita Kāśinātha Upādhyāya*
5. The *Uttaraparva* of *Bhaviṣya Purāṇa* (previously known as the *Bhaviṣyottara Purāṇa*) is provided with its Hindi translatio published by Hindi Sahitya Sammelana of *Prayāga*
6. *Mantramahodadhi* is a *Tāntrika nibandha* composed by *Mahīdhara Bhaṭṭa*, a *paṇḍita* from *Ahicchatra* residing in *Kāśī* famous for his *Vedadīpa* commentary on the *Madhyandina* recession of the *Vājasaneyī saṁhitā* of the *Śuklayajurveda*.
7. *Mahākālasaṁhitā* is a *Tāntrika* text.
8. *Varṣakṛtya* is a *Smṛti* digest composed by the *Maithilī paṇḍita Rudradhara*
9. *Varṣakṛtyakaumudi* is a *Smṛti* digest composed by the Bengali *paṇḍita Govindānanda Kavikaṅkanācārya* of Western Bengal
10. *Śāntikamalākara* & *Śūdrakamalākara* are *Smṛti* digests composed by *Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa*, a celebrated *Marāṭhi paṇḍita* of *Kāśī*.
11. *Smṛtisandarbha* is a collection of 56 *Smṛti* texts published by the Nag Publishers.
12. *Premānanda Premakatha* is a Bengali biography of *Svāmī Premānanda*, a direct disciple of *Śrī Śrī Rāmakṛṣṇa Paramahaṁsa Deva* & one of the first vice-presidents of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha* & Mission, composed by *Brahmacārī Akṣayacaitanya*
13. *Brahmānanda Līlākathā* is a Bengali biography of *Svāmī Brahmānanda* by *Brahmacārī Akṣayacaitanya*
14. *Śaktānandataraṅgiṇī* is a *Tāntrika nibandha* composed by *Brahmānanda Giri* of Eastern Bengal
15. *Mahabhāgavatam* is an *Upapurāṇa* is provided with its Bengali translation done by *paṇḍita  Pañcānana Tarkaratna*
16. *Śrī Śrī Sāradā Debī* - a Bengali biography of *Śrī Śrī Sāradāmaṇi Debī* composed by her disciple *Brahmacārī Akṣayacaitanya*
17. *Haribhaktivilāsa* is a *Gauṛīya Vaiṣṇava nibandha* composed by *Gopāla Bhaṭṭa Gosvāmī* & commented upon by *Sanātana Gosvāmī*, both of whom were direct disciples of *Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If the book happens to be too large & I am not interested in reading all of it, then I take the screenshots of only the relevant portions & create an album out of it. Here are the resulting albums

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also in the Google Photos, I have an such an album created out of *Caturvargacintāmaṇi*, *Devīrahasya* & *Nāradapañcarātra- Jñānāmṛtasāra*.

Recently I downloaded the webpages which contained *Kriyākramodyotikā*, *Kriyākairavacandrikā*, *Vārāhītantra*, *Kāmadhenutantra* & *Viśvasāratantra*

Comment: I could only scroll to reach to the end and missed the track of names of the books in your library. Thank you for posting. I might ask you details of some of the books in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism).